# HTML Form sends values to wrong PHP page

Tags: php, html

I just started learning PHP. I have this form that I have set the action to "dashboard.php". But, when I click the submit button, it send the user and variables to a file called newaccount.php. I don't know why this is happening and I have looked over my code. Any suggestions on how I can fix this problem?

Note: The HTML file is called newaccount.html, if that has anything to do with the problem.

HTML:

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"> Know Music</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-xs">
      <li><a href="#">Guitar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bass</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Drums</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Piano</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Create New Account</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div id="buffer">
  </div>
  <div id="text">
    <h8>Create A New Account</h8>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <form action="php/dashboard.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" class="w3-round-large in" name="email" value="E-Mail"><br>
      <br>
      <input type="password" class="w3-round-large in" name="wsp" value="Password"><br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" class="submit w3-round-large" value="Register">
    </form>
 </div>
 <div class="log">
   <p>Already have an account? <a class="link" href="#">Log In Here!</a></p>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

PHP (dashboard.php):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
 $user = $_POST["username"];
 $pass = $_POST["wsp"]; 
 echo $user; 
 echo $pass; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are the php file in the dashboard had some redirection function? Can you add your php code @ddjh5

Comment: Have you got a full copy of newaccount.html ? Your form might be inside another form?

Comment: Are you sure that dashboard.php isn't just redirecting to newaccount.php after it's done with whatever it needs to do?

Comment: @TheGooner I added your request to the question.

Comment: Do is your `dashboard.php` file actually in a folder called php ?

Comment: @giollianosulit Yes, it in a folder called php.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it would post to newaccount.php instead of dashboard.php. So when you access this file, you're accessing it, www.yourwebsite.com/newaccount.html ?

Comment: @giollianosulit Yes, I go to newaccount.html. I then hit the submit button and the page goes to newaccount.php instead of dashboard.php.

Comment: From everything you've posted here and said, the problem is not in any of the code we can see. You'll need to look elsewhere, maybe .htaccess is causing issues.

Comment: @giollianosulit I don't know what the problem was, but I restarted the XAMPP server and it then started working.

Comment: Ah ok, so it looks like it would be some kind of caching (apache) your PHP code.